# Can't handle drawerLayout with relativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, drawerlayout

I am developing an app in which I have taken a drawerLayout and a RelativeLayout .A relativeLayout contains An edittext,a button and a child linearLayout  with a webview.

**Problems with app**

1. when I ran app screen get divided in two view one view showing a white page with no content and 2nd is with another view with a edittext and screen with gray color.
2. when ran apk file on mobile, it is not installing -just showing installing progress but didn't install the app.

**xml file**

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/frame_container"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bsearch"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Esearch"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="GO"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/websearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Esearch"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText> </RelativeLayout> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**there are classes but i posted some needed classes here**

```
**mainActivityclass**


 package com.example.onebrowser;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText Gsearch;
    Button bsearch;
    WebView webView;
    Button b1;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
    private ArrayList<String>navDrawerIteams;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.websearch);
        bsearch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bsearch);
        Gsearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Esearch);

        mTitle=mDrawerTitle=getTitle();
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);



        Gsearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH)
                {

                    bsearch.performClick();
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        bsearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 String url=Gsearch.getText().toString();
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q="+url);
                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            }
        });

    }



}

  **2nd class**

        package com.example.onebrowser;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

        public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
            this.context = context;
            this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return navDrawerItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {       
            return navDrawerItems.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                        context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
            }

            ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

            imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
            txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

            // displaying count
            // check whether it set visible or not
            if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
                txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
            }else{
                // hide the counter view
                txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            return convertView;
        }
**3rd class**
package com.example.onebrowser;

public class NavDrawerItem {

    private String title;
    private int icon;
    private String count = "0";
    // boolean to set visibility of the counter
    private boolean isCounterVisible = false;

    public NavDrawerItem(){}

    public NavDrawerItem(String title, int icon){
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public NavDrawerItem(String title, int icon, boolean isCounterVisible, String count){
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.isCounterVisible = isCounterVisible;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }

    public int getIcon(){
        return this.icon;
    }

    public String getCount(){
        return this.count;
    }

    public boolean getCounterVisibility(){
        return this.isCounterVisible;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon){
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public void setCount(String count){
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void setCounterVisibility(boolean isCounterVisible){
        this.isCounterVisible = isCounterVisible;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried swiping the gray view away?

Comment: @freddieptf yes i tried ...but failed

Comment: @freddieptf checked my updated xml....... i tried to put some changed but nothing change got ....help

Comment: @freddieptf plz check my layouts wrap and fill_parent...

Comment: If that listview is for your drawer then make it the last layout in your xml, and make its background white so you can actually see it when you swipe

Comment: and for something more updated, check out https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: @freddieptf now one problem is there .that...... when swipe drawer from left and select item of list it gives same .. same a home for ever items .....

Comment: @freddieptf all problem solved but don't know ...  when i ran application searched google ,google opened but bottom side showing edittext .......

Comment: That's because you have an edittext in your layout, at the bottom. You can remove it if you don't need it, or set its visibility to gone

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @freddieptf i dont get that..why edittext displays on the screen.....  i type keywords in ediiext using google serch. to open it in webview ....webview opens correctly url but  at bottom it also shows edittext inwhich i had searched for google